# Selecting a specific row with duplicate values in a column but a blank value in one of the columns of the duplicate rows in R

Tags: r

I'm new to stack overflow. I'm sorry if the title is not comprehensible. I'll try to do a better job next time.

I have a data frame with duplicate values in the first column but the last column in their respective rows rows differ(few are blank and other might have some value in them). I have been trying to eliminate the duplicate with blank field in last column but every time I use 'duplicated()' or 'unique()' function, I'm only left with the row with blank field. This is possibly happening because the rows are sorted in such a way that the blank field is above the row which has a value in last column.

For example,
Input:

```
 *No.   per         hmm        qty*
  1    BARBIE123     new         1
  2    AYLIK32     * N/A*        1
  3    AYLIK32       new         1
  4     BARB         mid         1
```

Output I keep getting:

```
*No.   per      hmm        qty*
1    BARBIE    new         1
2    AYLIK   * N/A*        1
4     BARB     mid         1
```

Desired output:

```
*No.   per      hmm        qty*
1     BARBIE    new         1
3     AYLIK     new         1
4     BARB      mid         1
```

Is there a way I could specify which row to keep and which row to remove?

Appreciate all the help. Kindly let me know if the question is not comprehensible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you

```
df <- read.table(text="No.   per         hmm        qty*
1    BARBIE123     new         1
2    AYLIK32       N/A        1
3    AYLIK32       new         1
4     BARB         mid         1", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(!duplicated(per, fromLast=TRUE))

  # No.       per hmm qty.
# 1   1 BARBIE123 new    1
# 2   3   AYLIK32 new    1
# 3   4      BARB mid    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm, unsure if this is what you want. This will remove all rows with a NA.

```
df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
```

Lets say you have NAs in other columns and you dont want those taken into account. To only look at NAs in a single column, use this:

```
df <- df[complete.cases(df[,3]), ]
```

Where 3 is the # of the column you want to look for NAs in.